# How to transfer data between arduino and mysql data base?

Tags: arduino, communication

I am trying to create a database that communicates with the arduino to execute functions (such as activating leds) and read sensors to store the values in the database. 
I am confused on how to make this communication between mysql and arduino. 
some help?

Comment: What kind of hardware communications are you familiar with? Which are available on Arduino?

Comment: Ain't no Arduino on this planet gonna talk straight to MySQL.  You'll need a program on a larger computer.  Say, a PC or Raspberry Pi.  That program talks to both the Arduino and the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look up the [Firmata](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Firmata) library.  It runs over serial which the Arduino manages easily.

You're phased this question strangely .  Databases tend not to execute arbitrary code to control general IO.  That requires other code. You're looking at this architecture:-

[Arduino + Firmata] ------ [Firmata + some code + MySQL]

The some code can be any general programming language that you like and can get to talk to MySQL, and has a Firmata implementation.

PS. You might try a direct connection using native transport from something like an [MySQL Connector Arduino](https://www.arduinolibraries.info/libraries/my-sql-connector-arduino). I have no persomnal experience of this connector, but give it a bash by all means.

This is really a coding question thought isn't it?